# apache tomcat 8 ограничение доступа к папке с приложениями

Tags: java, tomcat

В локальной сети есть сервер tomcat8 на котором развернуто допустим 5 приложений соответственно в папке /opt/tomcat/webapps расположены 5 папок с приложениями app0,app1,app2,app3,app4

Админы наружу выпустили приложение app0 (прокидывают запросы через шлюз  напрямую по адресу: `http://ip-сервера_tomcat:8080/app0/` cнаружи получившийся адрес выглядит следующим образом: `http://app0.домен_компании.ru`

Дело в том что если ввести следующий адрес `http://app0.домен_компании.ru/..;/app1/` то получается получить доступ к внутренним приложением которые на внешку выпускать не планируется даже если я их застоплю в админке.

Подскажите каким образом сконфигурировать томкат чтобы пресечь эту возможность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно на внешку так как сделали ваши админы не выпускают а используют прокси например часто встречается такая связка как nginx + tomcat. Как вариант можно еще создать виртуальный  хост (виртуальный хост позволяет вам определять несколько имен хостов на одном сервере) добавляется он в файле  /tomcat8/server.xml в раздел  вот ссылка на более подробное описание:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html ну или если проще то можно сделать через админку Host Manager - это веб-приложение внутри Tomcat, которое создает / удаляет виртуальные хосты в Tomcat. Подробнее можно почитать тут https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/host-manager-howto.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]